# Why "This page isn't responding" warning in edge and chrome browser occures when I try to do continues activities in a web application(Angular8)

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, angular8, microsoft-edge

[Page not responding issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sPMM.png)

After this error I cant able do any activities in that page, I need to go close the tab and reopen another

```
Iam using a code to navigate to an array list (Next and Previous) using array indexing
Eg:
 NextClicked(){
        this.spinner.show('priority');
        let CurrentArray : any;
        this.buttonClicked = true
        this.bindStaff = false;
        this.NextClickCalled =true;
        console.log("======Next Clicked=====")
        let CurrentArrayElement = this.modelProject.ID
        console.log(CurrentArrayElement)
        CurrentArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CurrentProjectPageRecords'));
        console.log(CurrentArray);
        let CurrIndex =  CurrentArray.findIndex(x => x.ID === this.modelProject.ID);

CurrIndex = CurrIndex+1

let NextID = CurrentArray[CurrIndex].ID

 this.router.navigate(['/projects/' + NextID +'/edit/'+this.projectType]);

}
```

Next is to get the next element from the array and Previous is to navigate to previous. Continues use of this create the issue. if i clicked next for 5 times and click previous the page stuck there and shows the above mentioned browser warning

```
PreviousClicked(){
        this.spinner.show('priority');
        let CurrentArray : any;
        this.buttonClicked = true
        this.bindStaff = false;
        this.NextClickCalled =true;
        console.log("======Previous Clicked=====")
        let CurrentArrayElement = this.modelProject.ID
        console.log(CurrentArrayElement)
        CurrentArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CurrentProjectPageRecords'));
        console.log(CurrentArray);
        let CurrIndex =  CurrentArray.findIndex(x => x.ID === this.modelProject.ID);

CurrIndex = CurrIndex-1

let NextID = CurrentArray[CurrIndex].ID

 this.router.navigate(['/projects/' + NextID +'/edit/'+this.projectType]);

}
```

Don't know this is the exact issue but I got the warning by doing this activity continuously

[View API's Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvY4d.png)

Comment: Is that a javascript memmory issue or any kind of rendering issue

Comment: Hi, please provide some extra context to your question; code example, steps to reproduce, so the community can help you to narrow down the problem and to help you find a solution.

Comment: Does the error also occur in other browsers? You can open F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console. Besides, please provide more details about the issue. You can provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**, so that we can have a test and see how to help.

Comment: Iam using a code to navigate to an array list (Next and Previous) using array indexing Example code has been added in description

Comment: There is no errors in the Console, but some API takes time to load and stuck at there and the whole page is not responding.. If this happens then i need to close the current tab and open new tab to resolve it

Comment: The navigate methods look ok. You say *some API takes time to load and stuck at there*, maybe the stuck API is the cause of the issue. Which API do you use will stuck? You can check the API code and check how you call the API.

Comment: Google map is rendering when I navigate each time, may be this cause the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Enabling Lazy loading for angular resolved my issue

Talking about Angular and the CLI make sure to enable lazy loading and lazy load your routes, that way the initial payload stays smaller as your application grows more and more complex and full of features. Since the generated bundles are hashed they are cached properly thanks to the cache headers from the earlier section.

Check the below link for more details about lazy loading

[enter link description here](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-routing-lazy-loading-loadchildren/)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.